# facebook android sdk, permissions to public to stream with photo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to publish to a user's stream/timeline/wall

This will contain and image and a link and text, maybe text of the user's choosing. Anyway what permissions will I need to do this?

```
publish_stream
user_photos
```

a combination thereof? additional?

This is very different than the facebook sdk from days of olde (1 year ago), so I am not sure which permissions actually do what, despite their description

insight appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's the ["user" graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).

If you want to post to a user's timeline (using the /USER_ID/posts path), then you need the publish_stream permission - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Hi Ming, which one of the Android examples demonstrates publishing to stream, any?

Comment: See the HelloFacebookSample.